# User hirachy, One User can access others but among each other is no access

Tags: debian, users, group

I need a User(Master) which has access to other Users(users) files.

```
   Master
    /|\
   / | \
  /  | user3:user3
 /  user2:user2
user1:user1
```

The Users must not have access to each other, they all have their own group. Only the master should have additional access to the files.

Comment: This type of strict hierarchy doesn't fit with Linux's user model, unless "Master" is effectively root.  Would it be sufficient to put Master in user1's group, user2's group and user3's group.  It would mean the users would have the ability to remove access to Master by removing group-read from files.

Comment: Giving the "master" user root(sudo) permissions should work.